# how to save the array data into Laravel postgres?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-controller

How to store the following data into a database to ignore the null values too
[image: pic]

here is my database in postgres sql
[image],
where the UUID is project_id and array2 is indicators and array4 is the value column in the database.

Comment: please show us your trying

Comment: i am going to save the data into a database where each indicator has its own value, but i dont know how to make a good logic for storing data into the database,  please free to ask if u need view

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert an array into the column, change the column type, *indicator* can be changed to char var [] which accepts an array type, there's also integer[].

If you want to insert each row, and there will be 4/8 row, change the input.

Or you can create 2 new tables with a foreign key that corresponds to *project_id*, that accept each array as a different row.